# How to handle user interactive commands in Windows power shell?

Tags: windows, powershell

I need to execute the following command from Windows power shell:

```
PS C:\automation> ./test.exe get data "user\test" --outputfile test.csv

Please enter the Password:
Connecting database...
out file available in test.csv
PS C:\automation>
```

I need to enter the password, when its prompting for the password, in "Please enter the Password:". Then it will connect the database and gives output file.

Please guide me on how to automate this without using any 'subprocess' or 'pexpect' kind of things.

Comment: Are you asking how to automate the input of the password for `test.exe`? Isn't that what its `--password` parameter is for (see your command)?

Comment: 10/10, would automate again.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart My goodness... that was the typo error. Now see my modified question. Thanks.

Comment: So are you saying that `test.exe` does not have a `--password` parameter?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart YES you are right...!

Comment: If `test.exe` forces password input, there is little you can do to automate it. It depends on the executable.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart Do you mean, we can't automate this?

Comment: It is possible that you cannot. It depends on the design of `test.exe`. I recommend asking the author of the program.

Answer (score 0):

you can use wexpect which is a python module.Else use the one i created https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-4scr3fQpEcRlBDSTNLU252UzA/view?usp=sharing

Sample powershell script is attached in that zip.
Read this as well:
https://github.com/anilchander1/WindowsConsoleAutomator/blob/master/README.md

Make sure that you have the latest Microsoft VC++  redistributable is installed.